# My side left menu is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, sidebar

Im trying to devellop a side left menu, based on an example that I see on google, but when I click in my "Menu" to open the side menu, the menu dont opens.

This is my html, where I have a div id="menu" that is my menu that I want to show in my side left menu.

I also have a div id="content", that is a div that contains all of my content, I want to push this content to right When I click in my "Menu" to open the side left menu.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        </ul> 
</div>
<div id="content">
        <div id="menubar">
            <div id="open_menu">
                Menu
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Below, is the jQuery, that opens my side left menu with a toggle slow elffect and change the text of my Menu to Menu for Close, when the menu is open.

```
$('#open_menu').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#content').animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#open_menu').html('Close');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#content').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#open_menu').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
```

Do you see where can be the problem?

My fiddle with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Gezv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what toggle is for... check the jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Just use the click event and keep track of the status yourself one way or another. Here is a working example based on your fiddle:

```
$('#open_menu').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggled_on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('toggled_on');
        $('#content').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#open_menu').html('Menu');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('toggled_on');
        $('#content').animate({ left: 250 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#open_menu').html('Close');
        });
    }
});
```

This uses a class which is suboptimal, so unless you need it for something else just use a variable instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like I want, but I really thought that toggle was fine for this purpose!

Comment: You probably could use it, but I believe you would have less control of the animation. `.toggle()` toggles the element you call it on though (which is why the button disappeared in your original fiddle), so you could do something like this: `$('#open_menu').click(function(){$("#content").toggle()})` (which toggles the content, not the menu)